# Rotas Angular-JS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

boa noite! Sou novo na tecnologia de single page application, e estou encontrando dificuldades para renderizar minhas páginas no Angular um, eu possuo um botão que ao clicar, dispara uma rota, a mesma tenta ser carregada, mas não aparece na página, já pequisei e tentei de tudo, não sei onde estou errando

Meu modulo:

```
var modulo = angular.module("clienteCtrl", ["ngRoute"]);
```

Minha rota:

```
    modulo.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider

  .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "view/formCadastrarCliente.html"
      })

  .when("/cadastrarCliente", {
    templateUrl: "view/formCadastrarCliente.html"
  });

});
```

Meu HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bem - Vindo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.css">

<!-- Importação do Angular JS -->
<script src="libs/angular.js"></script>

<!-- Importação do ng-route angular -->
<script src="libs/angular-route.js"></script>

<!-- Importação do controller -->
<script src="js/clienteCtrl.js"></script>

<!-- Importação das rotas -->
<script src="js/rotasCliente.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app = "clienteCtrl">

<a href="#/cadastrarCliente">Cadastrar cliente</a>

<div ng-include = "'menu.html'"></div> 

<div ng-view></div>

<div ng-include = "'footer.html'"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Ao clicar no link, a url fica assim: http://localhost:8080/POC_Cast/index.html#!#%2FcadastrarCliente

Mas a página não carrega o conteúdo.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Você já tentou usar assim: `<a href="cadastrarCliente">Cadastrar cliente</a>`

Comment: @Sorack, já sim! Mas fazendo isso, ao clicar no link, o navegador exibe o erro 404. O mais estranho, é que do jeito que eu postei, ele tenta renderizar o conteúdo, mas não aparece nada na página.

Comment: Veja bem, a URL tá esquisita... tenta `./#/cadastrarCliente` OU `./cadastrarCliente`

Comment: @Sorack, Então, eu editei a minha pergunta com a minha nova rota, no .config... Se eu colocar para carregar o template no .when("/"), ele é carregado, logo que o documento html carrega no navegador... mas eu não entendi, na verdade me confundiu mais, eu queria que renderizasse apenas quando eu clicasse no link... ;(

Comment: Viu, tava revendo uns exemplos... mude o `href` para `#!/cadastrarCliente`

Comment: @Sorack, obrigado pela ajuda, de verdade! Era o erro que o amigo abaixo comentou, bem difícil mesmo de descobrir, mesmo pesquisando, não havia encontrado nada relativo! Mais uma vez eu agradeço e uma boa noite! xD

Comment: Opa tranquilo hehehe o @OnoSendai manja bastante de Angular mesmo, pode confiar

Comment: @Sorack eu não manjo, só lembro dos tropeços. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifique

```
modulo.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
```

para

```
modulo.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

        $routeProvider
```

Seu erro se dá por uma [mudança do comportamento padrão](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8) do angular 1.6.

Comment: Obrigado, @OnoSendai! Era isso, eu não sabia dessa novidade ... na verdade, preferia o outro comportamento padrão do angular.

Comment: @MatheusMinguini Sempre um prazer ajudar! Eu passei pelo mesmo problema a umas semanas atrás, por isso que lembrei da causa. =)

Comment: obrigado mais uma vez! :D